# How to align a child in main direction in react native?

Tags: react-native

How to align a child in the main direction in react native, for example:

IN react-native docs it has been only given for aligning in a cross direction

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do so with `justifyContent`

Comment: it is  for cross direction

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual problem is but I'm certain that the default flex-direction for `react-native` components is `column` therefore if you want to align vertically (main direction), you should use the `justifyContent` and `alignItems` for aligning horizontally (cross direction).

See this expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/rydNbb6oS

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for is flex Direction in the style

use

```
flexDirection:'column'
```

this is the default value and it aligns child components vertically

or

```
flexDirection:'row'
```

to align child components horizontally